# Using Gems with MacRuby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macruby

How do you use gems from a MacRuby .5 application on Snow Leopard? Do I need to specify the gem path? If so, how do I do this?

Best scenario is to package the gems inside the application so the user would not have to install them when the app is distributed.

Comment: UPDATE:
Rb-appscript does not work with MacRuby. Still not understanding why nokogiri is not though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yehuda Katz gem bundler is a very good option IMHO:

http://github.com/wycats/bundler

Anyway, there are many other options such as creating a vendor/ directory in your app bundle adding each vendor subdir to the ruby library search path in `rb_main.rb`:

```
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'vendor/rest-client/lib')
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'vendor/crack/lib')
require 'rest-client'
require 'crack'
```

I'm using the latter approach here:

http://github.com/rubiojr/canasto

Comment: This is nice, but very inconvenient for requiring a gem with many other dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

To use gems in a MacRuby project you need to use:

> $ sudo macgem install gem_name

Not all gems are compatible with MacRuby, yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you're packaging a MacRuby application you can also add the `--gem` flag with `macruby_deploy` under the "Info" tab for your Deployment target.

This puts the specified gem in the site_ruby folder deep within your package.

The arguments I'm passing macruby_deploy for my app are:

```
--compile --embed --gem sequel --gem sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2):

Gems that are written in C are not usable from MacRuby yet. So, no *nokogiri* for the time being.

To package the gems, the just released MacRuby 0.5 beta 2 includes the tool `macrubyc`, which packages the MacRuby framework inside your bundle. They also added support for doing this directly from Xcode in just one step.

Answer (score -5):

1st u will have to install the gem:

```
$ sudo gem install gem_name
```

then simply require it on your program, u will have to require the 'rubygems' also:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gem_name'
```

Comment: Hi Raafat,

Thanks for the reply. I have the gems installed and use them everyday in normal scripting. I am requiring rubygems and the gems after that. The error is a load error. 

These are working:
require 'rubygems'
require 'bacon'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

This is not.
require 'nokogiri'
require 'appscript'